# Using @EnvironmentObject properties with CADisplayLink

Tags: swift, swiftui, cadisplaylink

I'm trying to implement `CADisplayLink` for some animations, but when I try to access my `MainData` environment object properties from inside class `MyAnimations`, I get the fatal error `No ObservableObject of type MainData found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for MainData may be missing as an ancestor of this view.`

In SceneDelegate, I have `MainData` set as an environment object on `ContentView`:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var mainData = MainData()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(self.mainData))
            
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

...

}
```

And here's the class with `CADisplayLink`. `createDisplayLink()` is called from `ContentView`:

```
class MyAnimations: NSObject{
    @EnvironmentObject var mainData: MainData

    
    func createDisplayLink() {
        let displaylink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(step))
        
        displaylink.add(to: .current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
    }
    

    @objc func step(link: CADisplayLink) {
        mainData.displayLinkY += 1.5   //Error here
        mainData.displayLinkX += 1.5
    }
    
    
}
```

**My question is:** how can I change environment object properties `displayLinkX` and `displayLinkY` from inside `step()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `@EnvironmentObject` property wrapper, it is for SwiftUI only

```
class MyAnimations: NSObject{
    var mainData: MainData

    init(mainData: MainData) {
      self.mainData = mainData
        super.init()
    }

    // ... other code
}
```

Comment: Xcode wants me to add an initializer, but when I add `override init() {...` I get the error `Property 'self.mainData' not initialized at implicitly generated super.init call`. What do I initialize mainData to? Do you know what I mean?